# How get Superfish to display on mobile device?

Tags: 7, navigation

I installed the Superfish Module and Library and it works on a desktop/laptop/tablet. It collapses correctly when I re-size the screen. But it won't display at all on a mobile device. I tried different settings on the Config page and tried adding the recommended code in html.tpl.php:
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
I enabled SF-Smallscreen with the jQuery sf-Smallscreen plugin. Made sure it was weighted to appear at the top of all the blocks.
Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I discovered my .css for the page was HIDING Superfish. Removed the offending code and Superfish on mobile works fine.